# How can I know whether a window is open C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, msdn

In my c++ application I need to know if a curtain window that was open by a different application got closed by the user or not.

All I have is the windows title.

Trying to use the function:

```
 FindWindowA(
    _In_opt_ LPCSTR lpClassName,
    _In_opt_ LPCSTR lpWindowName);
```

and checking if the returning HWND is null doesn't work because even after user closes the window the function returns a non null handle.
Using:

```
EnumWindows(
            _In_ WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc,
            _In_ LPARAM lParam);
```

function and going over all open windows was too complicated since I need to stay in my original code function and not pass the implementation to a procedure that's out of my class( and there is no access to class members there).

Can anyone help pls??

Comment: `FindWindow` should return NULL if the window isn't found. How do you get non-NULL for a closed window?

Comment: I don't know, but I press X to close the window, and checking afterwards with debbuger that function, and the  return value is not null

Comment: Is it an app that doesn't actually destroy its window when you click the close button but only hides it?

Comment: If it does hide rather than close you can `IsWindowVisible()`

Comment: thanks!! this works for me and enough to my needs (the app probably hides only the window)